# Class ArticlesTableSeeder does not exist, but ArticlesTableSeeder exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration, homestead

I have created a project using Laravel 5.4 and Homestead. I created a seed using `php artisan make:seeder ArticlesTableSeeder`, which results in a 'seeder created successfully' message. The seeder is in database/seeds/**ArticlesTableSeeder.php** and looks like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ArticlesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Article::truncate();

        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();

        for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
            Article::create([
                'title' => $faker->sentence,
                'body' => $faker->paragraph,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run `php artisan db:seed --class=ArticlesTableSeeder` I get this error:

```
[ReflectionException]                     
Class ArticlesTableSeeder does not exist
```

What's going on here?

Comment: I don't see what is wrong either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `composer du` command before using newly created seeder class.